# How do i reattach jquery function to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I reattach function to a html element in jQuery. Let me have many anchor tags and the JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //doing some manipulation and making ancher html string and replacing with current ancher tags like i.e
    var newAncherTags = "mytest1";
    $(this).replaceWith(newAncherTags); // using replacewith method is my requirement
  });
  $('#a').click(function() {
    //definition
  });
  $('#b').click(function() {
    //definition
  });
  $('#c').click(function() {
    //definition
  });
  $('#d').click(function() {
    //definition
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="a">test1</a>
<a href="#" id="b">test2</a>
<a href="#" id="c">test3</a>
<a href="#" id="d">test4</a>
```

After replacing anchor tags event lost, click function is not working. It it is not related to only one html pages i have many pages which I could not change jQuery function going on every html page like

```
$(document).on('click','#a', function(event) {});
```

The function for manipulation over anchor tags is in one file so I want to do something in this function.

Comment: You'd be better off hiding the element instead of destroying it.

Comment: And why are you not able to change `$('#a').click(function(){` to `$(document).on('click','#a', function(event) {});` ?

Comment: Or even add a class to the anchors `$(document).on('click','.anchor', function(event) {})` so you don't need to repeat code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same solution you have used.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //doing some manipulation and making ancher html string and replacing with current ancher tags like i.e
    var newAncherTags = "mytest1";
    $(this).replaceWith(newAncherTags); // using replacewith method is my requirement
  });
  $(document).on("click", '#a', function() {
    //definition
  });
  $(document).on("click", '#b', function() {
    //definition
  });
  $(document).on("click", '#c', function() {
    //definition
  });
  $(document).on("click", '#d', function() {
    //definition
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="a">test1</a>
<a href="#" id="b">test2</a>
<a href="#" id="c">test3</a>
<a href="#" id="d">test4</a>
```